# why did't work this slider in My Laravel app

Tags: php, jquery, css, laravel-5

I need add this example slider to My Laravel project http://wpandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/

and I add this to My blade file like this way

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <meta name="description" content="jQuery Logo Slider Ticker by webdesignandsuch.com">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <script src="{{('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').bxSlider({
            ticker: true,
            tickerSpeed: 5000,
            tickerHover: true
        });
        });
        </script>

        <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="slider-container">

    <ul id="slider">
        <li><a href="#"><p>kkkkkkk</p></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/2.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/3.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/4.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/5.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/6.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/7.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/8.jpg')}}"></a></li>
    </ul>

</div><!-- /slider -->
```

when I check crome console here it displayed following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/js/vendor/holder.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/js/vendor/holder.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):87 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bxSlider is not a function
http://localhost:8000/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have js and css folder in public folder

but above slider not working. only display (not moving) how can fix this?
how can fix this

**updated**

I am using bootstrap theme for My web. is it problem?

Comment: Are you correctly importing the library - `bxSlider`?

Comment: Make sure that assets are stored in `public` folder.

Comment: what did you mean correctly importing the library - bxSlider?

Comment: yes assets are store in public folder

Comment: how to importing library bxSlider @Saumya Rastogi